# String Buffers in String Processing Subroutines

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm currently creating some string processing subroutines using mips assembly language and I've run into a problem. 
Each subroutine takes an output address as an argument, which serves as the memory location where the newly processed string will be written. At first I had subroutines write bytes directly to the output address, but soon realised I should instead write to a temporary string buffer, process it, then copy the buffer contents to the output address.
The question is, how do I go about doing this?
Declaring a global static string buffer in main.asm with .space was one solution, but can be problematic when one string processing subroutine is called by another and starts overwriting the caller's string data. Using the runtime stack to store string data was another solution, but comes with its own set of problems.

Is this a common problem? What is the best practice for handling this type of situation?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use the stack unless you need to fit massive strings. Otherwise, use the heap (i.e. memory allocated using something like `malloc`).

Answer (score 0):

**Copying is slow, avoid it whenever possible.**

You have 2 good options:

- copy-and-compute: e.g. a string-reversal function that starts at the end of the output buffer, writing backwards while reading forwards.  Or vice versa because the end of the input might already be hot in cache.  And you want to leave the start of the output hot in cache, so writing it last is good for medium to large strings.  You can easily do whole words (or SIMD vectors) at a time if you have a byte-swap instruction, if both input and output have the necessary alignment.
- in-place: e.g. string-reversal by starting with pointers to the start and end, and walking them in towards each other until they cross in the middle.  Going more than 1 byte at a time requires checking to avoid overlap as they cross.  (Although if you restrict yourself to word-aligned loads/stores then you already have to deal with that, and depending on alignment + length it might not be easy to go fast.)

If you were using implicit-length strings and had to `strlen` the input, then the end of the input is already hot in cache and you should start reading there.  Some algorithms you can start writing the output before knowing how long it's going to be so it would be even worse if you needed to strlen first just to find out how big a scratch array you needed.

You might even implement both copy and in-place versions of some operations in different functions to give your caller the option, depending on whether they need to keep the original around or not.  If care about performance enough to hand-write in asm, design your API to make it possible to avoid unnecessary copying.

(For some algorithms, copy and in-place can use the same code.)

**Normally you *can* just process into the output buffer.**

You can specify (in comments / documentation / a C function signature with a `char *restrict outbuf` arg) that your function writes its output before reading all of its input, so overlapping the input and output won't necessarily work.

If exactly in-place is supported, (e.g. for a function that uppercases every alphabetic input character, where `out[i]` depends only on `in[i]`), then you can document that, too, even if partial overlap wouldn't.  (e.g. if writing `out[i]` destroys `in[i+something]`)

A function like that would work as exactly in-place or as a non-overlapping copy-and-upcase.

---

**If you do need a tmp buffer** for some reason:

- If your tmp buffer size is small and fixed-size (not scaling with input string length), allocate it on the callstack.
- **Punt the problem to your caller: ask your caller to supply a tmp buffer of the right size as an extra argument**.  Then your caller can reuse this space across multiple calls, as long as its large enough for the largest callee.

Your caller might know that it doesn't need to be reentrant or thread-safe and can use a static buffer.  Or it might know that the max size is low enough that it can safely use the stack without risk of a stack overflow.

Of course dynamic allocation + free is possible as a worst-case fallback for large strings.  On a toy OS like MARS or SPIM I think there's a `syscall` for that.  On a real MIPS there will normally be some kind of `malloc` library function you can use with an optimized allocator that maintains a free-list.  You want to avoid making an actual system call to get and free a small buffer.

You could even check at runtime if the size is small and decide to use stack space (and branch at the end of your function, too, to decide whether to `free` or just adjust the stack pointer.)